# Its possible to the same event overlap in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, events, locking, overlap

I was wondering if its possible to the same event on MySQL overlap its execution:

eg:
I have this event scheduled to execute every 2 seconds:

```
BEGIN   
 DELETE FROM RouteDatabase3.route_fast WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, updated_at, now()) > 5; 
END
```

What happens if this event takes 10 seconds? MySQL server will execute the same event overlaping the last one?

Its possible to lock the event execution, so MySQL will execute only one at time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution using the [GET_LOCK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and [RELEASE_LOCK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock) functions from MySQL,

```
BEGIN   
 IF GET_LOCK('lock', 5) THEN
  DELETE FROM RouteDatabase3.route_fast WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, updated_at, now()) > 5; 
  SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('lock');
  END IF;
END
```